# Arabic query string data appearing as Junk

Tags: asp.net, encoding, query-string, arabic

I have an application where I am getting a query string as arabic. The data appears to be ok almost all the time. But at some instances the data gets junk. I thought its a problem with the font. But when i tried the application in a machine where arabic is not installed it worked perfectly. My major problem is the numbers appearing the query string.
eg:

```
http://www.domain.com/page.aspx?d=٣٤٦٧ رس
```

Here my application sometimes gets all the data correctly as 3467 RS, but sometimes it comes as ???? RS.

Do anyone know any method to make this correct.
I tried saving my client page in Arabic ISO encoding but that too didn't helped

Answer (score 0):

Use url encoding and decoding for this purpose. If you are working with javascript , visit the following link for reference:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp